# Sending a pdf file to client from server through web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, jakarta-ee

As I am new to web service can you please tell the answer of my question.
My question is

> I want to implement a web service which sends pdf files to client as the client calls this web service.

Please someone help me with nice piece of code or explanation.

Now can some one please solve my error.

> 12-23 09:42:48.429: DEBUG/installd(32): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/vmdl33143.tmp' ---
>   12-23 09:42:51.708: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.730: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.749: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.759: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.779: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.779: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.819: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.830: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/Wbxml;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.840: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/WbxmlParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.900: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/WbxmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.910: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/syncml/SyncML;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.910: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/wml/Wml;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.929: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/wv/WV;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.929: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:51.949: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
>   12-23 09:42:53.299: INFO/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
>   12-23 09:42:53.319: INFO/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
>   12-23 09:42:53.329: INFO/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
>   12-23 09:42:53.350: INFO/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
>   12-23 09:42:53.350: INFO/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
>   12-23 09:42:53.370: INFO/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
>   12-23 09:42:53.499: INFO/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
>   12-23 09:42:53.560: INFO/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
>   12-23 09:42:53.570: INFO/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;'
>   12-23 09:42:53.659: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.668: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.668: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.668: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.680: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.690: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.709: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.709: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/Wbxml;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.719: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/WbxmlParser;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.719: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/WbxmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.719: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/syncml/SyncML;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.719: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/wml/Wml;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.719: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/wv/WV;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.719: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.719: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;': multiple definitions
>   12-23 09:42:53.829: DEBUG/dalvikvm(328): DexOpt: load 867ms, verify 1752ms, opt 108ms
>   12-23 09:42:54.029: DEBUG/installd(32): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/vmdl33143.tmp'(success) ---

This the Error in DDMS of android emulator.

Now my web service & code looks likes this.

Code:-

```
package com.uks.webservice;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.rmi.Remote;  

public interface SendPDF extends Remote {

    public String[] sendPDF() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
            Exception;
}
```

Main Class from web service is created:-

```
package com.uks.webservice;

import java.io.File;   
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStream;  

import javax.activation.DataHandler;  
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;  

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;  

public class SendPDFImpl implements SendPDF {

@Override
public String[] sendPDF() {

    String[] pdfFile = new String[2];
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    File file = new File(
            "C:/eclipse/workspace/AIPWebService/src/test.pdf");
    DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(file));
    String readLine = null;
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Web Service Called Successfully");
        stream = dh.getInputStream();
        // BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        // new InputStreamReader(stream));
        while (offset < data.length
                && (numRead = stream.read(data, offset, data.length
                        - offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }
        readLine = encoder.encode(data);
        // while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("'Reading File............................");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Data Reading Successful");

        pdfFile[0] = file.getName();
        pdfFile[1] = readLine;

        stream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pdfFile;
}
}
```

Web Service:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://webservice.uks.com"
    xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://webservice.uks.com"
    xmlns:intf="http://webservice.uks.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!--
        WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4 Built on Apr 22, 2006
        (06:55:48 PDT)
    -->
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://webservice.uks.com"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <element name="sendPDF">
                <complexType />
            </element>
            <element name="sendPDFResponse">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="sendPDFReturn" type="xsd:String" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="sendPDFRequest">

        <wsdl:part element="impl:sendPDF" name="parameters" />

    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="sendPDFResponse">

        <wsdl:part element="impl:sendPDFResponse" name="parameters" />

    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="SendPDFImpl">

        <wsdl:operation name="sendPDF">

            <wsdl:input message="impl:sendPDFRequest" name="sendPDFRequest" />

            <wsdl:output message="impl:sendPDFResponse" name="sendPDFResponse" />

        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="SendPDFImplSoapBinding" type="impl:SendPDFImpl">

        <wsdlsoap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

        <wsdl:operation name="sendPDF">

            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />

            <wsdl:input name="sendPDFRequest">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />

            </wsdl:input>

            <wsdl:output name="sendPDFResponse">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />

            </wsdl:output>

        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="SendPDFImplService">

        <wsdl:port binding="impl:SendPDFImplSoapBinding" name="SendPDFImpl">

            <wsdlsoap:address
                location="http://localhost:8080/AIPWebService/services/SendPDFImpl" />

        </wsdl:port>

    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

And Now My Android Code.

```
package com.uks.android.webservice;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.widget.TextView;  

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;  
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;  
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;  
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;  

public class PDFActivity extends Activity {  
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "sendPDF";  
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://webservice.uks.com/";  
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;  
    private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.123:8080/AIPWebService/services/SendPDFImpl";  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView textViewOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewOne);
        TextView textViewTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTwo);
        try {
            SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

            textViewOne.setText("Web Service Started");
            AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            textViewTwo.setText(result.toString());
            // Object result = envelope.getResponse();
            // FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(name, mode)

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert file to byte array and pass it on to service on server do the reverse to get file back.

- <del>[Here is very good article on doing this using JAXWS](http://geemonkb.blogspot.com/2009/01/jax-wx-streaming-soap-attachments.html)</del>

Comment: Please tell me how to use that in Apache Axis.

Comment: Thanks for the article,cleared my idea about how to send larger files.

Comment: Sorry for delay I am busy in coding this web service.Thanks for answer.

Comment: Shashank sama O genki desu ka?

Comment: @Jigar, I don't know much about Japanese, Mehul may be saying: Mr. Shashank, are you alright?

Comment: http://geemonkb.blogspot.com/2009/01/jax-wx-streaming-soap-attachments.html is down now. I found another article: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=6888

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/milan/entry/jax_ws_tutorial_working_with This is even better & more official.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java EE 6 technology, it fits your purposes good. 
Just create a web-service, which will return byte array within a responce on GET.

See [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/beta/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_jaxrs_configjaxrs11method.html) manual.

Comment: Sorry man I am bit confused between which web service API to use.As I am using eclipse which has built in support of Apache Axis.Can you please tell me about that.Or please make aware of different API's used in web service technology.

Comment: the ide is not so important here, more important is your server, does it really support jee 6.

Comment: I exactly don't know but can say yes because I am using Apache Tomcat 6.0.20

Comment: @VladimirIvanov the given link is not valid