# How do I transfer files with jax-ws?

Tags: java, web-services, file, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I'm developing a Applet->WebServices complete system which work with files.
I need to upload and download files from my WebService.
I've searched and found that MTOM can do it, but I can't find any examples.

Comment: Please check out answer of this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507201/sending-a-pdf-file-to-client-from-server-through-web-service which contains an example.